# Checkbox not completing completing function html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have multiple check boxes in my webpage. Each checkbox runs a javascript function called "adds". This works when you click the box manually.

I have another type of checkbox which checks all the check boxes in that div, but when this is checked it does not run the function "adds" on the checkboxes it checks.

Does anyone know why?

Check all in div function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function checkCheckboxes( id, pID ){
$('#'+pID).find(':checkbox').each(function(){
jQuery(this).prop('checked', $('#' + id).is(':checked'));
});  
}
</script>
```

Adds Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function adds(id) {

var value = $(id).val()

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "selection_update.php",
        data: {"value": value},
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
            success:function(responce){
            $("#check").html(responce);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

I call the adds function through this:

```
<input class="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" value="$table3[Test_ID]" onchange="adds('#tccb$j')" id="tccb$j" unchecked>
```

and call the checkall function through:

```
<input class="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="checkCheckboxes(this.id, 'collapse$count');" id="mcb$count" unchecked/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply changing the 'checked' property will not trigger the event. You need to use `.trigger( "change" )` or `.change()` as well.

Your key line will look like this...

```
jQuery(this).prop('checked', $('#' + id).is(':checked')).change();
```

Comment: Did this work well enough to be accepted as the answer? Or are you unable to accept because of your low reputation score?